# Why do species not absorb an electron in mass spectrometry?

Tags: electrons, mass-spectrometry

The following is a direct quote from my high-school chemistry text-book regarding **mass spectrometry**:

> The ionization process in the mass spectrometer involves an electron from an electron gun hitting the incident species and removing an electron. The collision can be so energetic that it causes the molecule to break up into different fragments.

This fails to make sense to me for two reasons:

1. Why wouldn't the majority of these electrons simply pass through a given substance, like the alpha particles in Rutherford's Gold Foil Experiment?
2. Why do positive ions/functional groups, such as ammonia, not absorb these electrons, instead of allowing them to break the species apart (and make them more positive in the process)?

Any justifications for these discrepancies would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Partial answer to 2. "In electron impact (E.I.) mass spectrometry the molecule is bombarded with highly energetic electrons that knock a weakly bound electron out of the molecule. If you think this is strange, think of throwing bricks at a brick wall: the bricks do not stick to the wall but knock loose bricks off the top of the wall." (from Clayden's *Organic Chemistry*). The electrons have too much energy to be absorbed.

Comment: The 'duplicate question' is fine in so far as it goes but it does not  answer part (1) or part (2) of this question   but states that energetic electrons can ionise molecules. (Neither does it give any details such as cross section for ionisation vs. electron impact energy etc.) You should certainly ask part(1) again as this has been closed off here.